# Animating size change with Storyboard

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to change the size of a ScrollViewer by using a storyboard, but it is not animating, it just change the size of the scrollviewer instantly after the delay.

Here are the variants I tried so far:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="ShowMenuStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="changeHeight" 
                             Duration="0:0:2" 
                             EnableDependentAnimation="True" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                             To="500" />
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Name="ShowMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScrollViewer.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="900"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScrollViewer.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="640"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Name="ShowSomeThing">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="640" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="900" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer" d:IsOptimized="True"/>

</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Name="MaybeNow">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer" d:IsOptimized="True">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="900"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer" d:IsOptimized="True">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="640"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

</Storyboard>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So without seeing the full implementation I'll just make the assumption that it's likely because while although you do indeed have `To` value declared, you still need a `From` value in some form or it can't create the Keyframes for the animation in between.

Below is a simple example. Notice the Set Height/Width on the `ScrollViewer` itself. These act as inherited `From` values. Which, if needed you could include directly in your Storyboards or via other methods.

**visual output (in a choppy gif format);**
[image]

**XAML PoC;**

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="CW_AnimSCSizeSample">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="500"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="700"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Content="Animate SV Size 1 time"
                Click="play_CW_AnimSCSizeSample"/>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="1"
                      Height="200" Width="300" 
                      Background="LightBlue" 
                      BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3"/>


    </Grid>
```

**Code behind to start the Storyboard from your .cs;**

```
private void play_CW_AnimSCSizeSample(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CW_AnimSCSizeSample.Begin();
        }
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Hi, that's it! Thank you. 
"These act as inherited From values. Which, if needed you could include directly in your Storyboards or via other methods." helped me out, because I had {Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Page} in use, and those aren't automatically providing the "from" value.
It looks like any binding aren't providing the information, so I will have to do that manually right before I begin() the Storyboard..

Comment: Freue mich zu helfen :)